# KIK Share data-url is broken?

Tags: javascript, kik

I've noticed that the Kik share button has a data-url attribute, and [the documentation](http://dev.kik.com/share/) even has a share button builder which supports URL's, but in my testing, the data-url attribute is ignored, instead it always shares the current URL.

Here's an example:

```
<a class="kik-button kik-color-lg" 
   data-url="http://example.com/something" 
   data-title="Something" 
   data-description="Something" 
   data-pic="http://example.com/example.png">
</a>
```

If you are on the page http://example.com - pressing the share button will share a card which brings you to http://example.com NOT http://example.com/something

I also noticed there isn't actually any "url" item when using `kik.send` natively, leading me to confusion to what's actually supposed to have been sent.

Another semi-related issue is that I'm trying to hide the share button on non-kik devices, so they can still use the site like normal, however `kik.enabled` is only true when the user first loads the page, as soon as they navigate to another page, `kik.enabled` is suddenly false, causing the share button to disappear.  Why is this?

(Note: kik.enabled works perfectly fine when using the Kik Developer tools in Chrome, @kik devs, I really wish the Developer Tools were closer to the Kik App, I've built a few apps and usually they work fine in my browser with the Kik tools, but are completely broken within Kik itself)

Comment: can you provide a sample code or live link to your current project ?

Answer (score -1):

The [the kik-share-button script](http://cdn.kik.com/kik/1.0.18/kik-share.js) tries to send the value of `data-url` as a `url` parameter to `kik.send()` :

```
function setupShareButton(link) {
    link.style.display = "inline-block";
    link.setAttribute("title", "Share this on Kik!");
    link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var link = this,
            data = {},
            n, m, i, h;
        n = link.getAttribute("data-title");
        if (n) {
            data.title = n
        } else {
            data.title = document.title
        }
        m = link.getAttribute("data-description");
        if (m) {
            data.text = m
        }
        i = link.getAttribute("data-pic");
        if (i) {
            data.pic = i
        }
        h = link.getAttribute("data-url");
        if (h) {
            data.url = h
        }
        kik.send(data);
        // don't follow the link normally unless a previous command threw an error
        return false
    })
}
```

But the [kik.send()](http://dev.kik.com/docs/#messaging-send) documentation doesn't mention the `url` parameter. It's possible that this is an error in the share button script. An invalid parameter name would likely result in the default behavior of sending the current page's url. Maybe it is meant to be part of the `data` parameter:

```
kik.send({
  title: '...',
  text: '...',
  data: {url: '...'}
})
```

in which case a small modification to the share button script could produce the correct functionality.